# Suppressing some messages in R but leaving others?

Tags: r

I'm an R newbie using RScaLAPACK and every time I spawn a new process grid I get a message.

```
> sla.gridInit(2)
[1] "RScaLAPACK:Process Grid Initialized "
```

I'm going to put this line in a function and I don't want my function to be spitting out this message.  However- I don't want to just sink("/dev/null") the call because for all I know, something somewhere could go wrong and then I'd be suppressing useful output.  Basically, I want it to be silent when it succeeds and loud if it fails.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Any thoughts, including design considerations, are welcome.

edit:
sla.gridInit() isn't returning anything.  The code for sla.gridInit just calls print().

edit:
I suppose capturing output is best like in [suppress messages displayed by "print" instead of "message" or "warning" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797314/suppress-messages-displayed-by-print-instead-of-message-or-warning-in-r) . At least I will have the output if I want to do something with it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can wrap this function in one of the suppress* functions, `suppressMessages`, `suppressWarnings` or `suppressPackageStartupMessages`. See the help pages of those functions for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  I googled for suppressMessages and found another question like this.  Turns out suppressMessages can't deal with output from print(). :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797314/suppress-messages-displayed-by-print-instead-of-message-or-warning-in-r