# suppress messages displayed by “printf” in C++ code instead of “message” or “warning” in R

Tags: c, r

Just [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797314/suppress-messages-displayed-by-print-instead-of-message-or-warning-in-r), except this package author is EVEN MORE vexing and is using `printf` and `snprintf` to display a mix of messages, warnings, and errors in the C/C++ code:

```
library('inline')
silly_developer_cxx_function <- cxxfunction(
  signature(x = "integer"),
  'printf("%s", "Seriously! Thanks for using my function!!");
  return ScalarReal(INTEGER(x)[0]);'
  )
silly_developer_function <- function(i){
  print("Thanks for using my function!!")
  return(silly_developer_cxx_function(as.integer(i)))
}
```

I can suppress the R-level print statement with `capture.output`, but the `sprintf` statement seems un-killable:

```
> capture.output(x <- silly_developer_function(1L), file='/dev/null')
Seriously! Thanks for using my function!!
```

Comment: That's a serious implementation flaw, have you contacted the author of the package? Maybe she thinks it's funny, but to us all it's just annoying...

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo I am contacting the author of the package in question, but am trying to work around the bug in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Zach, do you have more context?   Are you talking about the CRAN Package [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) which I once mentored for Google Summer of Code and later maintained (and which is now in the very capabable hands of Tomoaki Nishiyama) as CRAN does not allow actual `printf` or `std::cout` per [Section 6.5 of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Printing).

You can generally reach maintainers of the DB packages on r-sig-db which Tomoaki reads, and we have (had?) a dedidated list for rpostgresql as well.  Tomoaki is very responsive, and I suggest using the proper venue.  Venting is not going help. I only caught it because you (mistakenly?) stuck the `Rcpp` tag on this.   Or did you by chance mean the (very different) [rpg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpg/index.html) by Tim Keitt, yet mistakenly referred to [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) instead?

*Edit:*  Some history.  We never had proper backend to PostgreSQL.  So suggested this as topic for Google Summer of Code, and a student took it and wrote a first, somewhat hackish version.  Chiefly by looking what RMySQL did and adapting to the PostgreSQL API.  Because behaviour was defined by the R / S definition of the Database Interface -- DBI.

So what you appear to complain about are things like (first `grep` find in the RPostgreSQL sources)

```
    (void) sprintf(buf, msg, (int) mgr->length);
    RS_DBI_errorMessage(buf, RS_DBI_ERROR);
```

and I would hence be fairly certain that RMySQL does the same.  Given that this is a programmatic use if the prepared string (or, rather, `char` vector), I would think that you can in fact suppress this.

If I were you, I'd take a look at the source and/or ask on r-sig-db.

Comment: Hi Dirk, Sorry about that.  I fixed the tags.  I do indeed mean `RPostgreSQL` on CRAN.  It uses `sprintf` and `snprintf`, which seem to be a variant of `printf` (although it's hard for me to tell).  Their output seems to bypass R.  E.g. `capture.output(suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(x <- dbGetQuery(con, 'bogus query;'))), file='/dev/null'); print(x)`, where con is a connection to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: If it helps, my session info is: `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgreSQL_0.4 DBI_0.3.1  `

Comment: I *think* you misunderstand. Look at manual page, or C library site. Both `sprintf` and `snprintf` print to a _string_, hence the leading s. What matters with that string is what matters.  R is oicky about NOT letting us use direct `(f)printf` precisely because one cannot filter / suppress from R because these would be outside of R's I/O. Hence Section 6.5 of WRE as I mentioned.

Comment: Hmmm, so the un-supressable print statement I'm seeing must be coming from the postgres driver itself.  I had (wrongly) assumed it must be emanating from RPostgreSQL

Comment: Indeed. I would be *very surprised* if RPostgreSQL had managed to sneak unsuppressable messages past the CRAN maintainers. This is a very clear check, and I *very certain* that the package is clean.  The external library, as you point, is an entire matter.  So there: just rewrite that library ;-)

Comment: How would I pass the `--quiet` flag to Postgres through `dbGetQuery()`?

Comment: Not sure, that may be a request for an API extension. You can reach Tomoaki at the list ;-)

Comment: With libpq, you might try setting the error verbosity. 'rpg' exposes that. I can't recall if you can do this via setting options using a simple query.